# Determining Consecutive Numbers in a 2D Integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array of varying size, where height can take on any value.

```
int array[][] = new int[height][height]
```

Let's say I have a 3 x 3 array with the values of:

7 8 9

6 5 4

1 2 3

Would it be possible to check to see if 1 is adjacent to 2, 2 adjacent to 3, 3 adjacent to 4, 4 adjacent to 5 and so on? Adjacent here being if they are next to each other vertically, horizontally and diagonally.

So basically, there is a link from number 1 to 9 (or maximum number - e.g. if board is a 4x4, then from 1 to 16).

Comment: By adjacent you mean (+1) or (-1) right ?

Comment: By adjacent I mean if there is one above, below, to the left, to the right, and to the corners if they exist.

Let's say we're looking at 5 in this array.  It would check the locations where 7,8,9,6,4,1,2,3 lay and check to see if a 6 is there.

Comment: So, if we have '1' then is the number '2' near it somewhere, horizontally, vertically ?

Comment: Horizontally, vertically and diagonally.

Comment: does array[0][0] have to be 1 ? or any number ?

Comment: Why can't you just iterate over adjacent coordinates of a given number, and compare each value to another argument?

Comment: Array[0][0] can be any number. The order of the numbers can be random.

Comment: Yes its possible. You just need to write some code. Why don't you try something and update your question with your effort.

Comment: We can reformulate the question: check if there is uninterrupted path encoded in step numbers over two-dimensional map.

Comment: I haven't really understood the question, do we have to check if the entire array is neatly arranged, or do we have to check if it the number has its predecessor around it somewhere?

Comment: It has to have its predecessor immediately after itself. 

So 2 follows a 1, 3 follows a 2, 4 follows a 3 and so on until we reach the maximum value.

They can follow each other horizontally, diagonally or vertically.

I keep trying code of my own and my code is incorrect as it will check indices out of bounds.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao: Please stop suggesting edits like this. Sprinkling bold and inline code formats around don't make the post any easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I have been been able to make. It's a good solution, although takes a little more space. Definitely not the best solution for this though. Use of math might be needed for a more optimum solution. I am not that good at math.

```
//assuming the height as variable - 'r'
//take an input of some element, let's assume a[0][0], taken inside a[e][e]

int f, f1, f2, arflg=0;
int arr = new int[r*r];
for(int i=0;i<r;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<r;j++){
        arr[arflg]=a[i][j];
        arflg++;
        if(a[i][j]==a[e][e]) f1 = arflg; //location of element entered on the array
        if(a[i][j]==a[e][e]-1) f2 = arflg; //location of element's predecessor on the array
    }
}
f = f2 - f1;
if(f==1){
//forward hortizontal
}elseif(f==-1){
//backward horizontal
}elseif(f==r){
//below
}elseif(f==r-1){
//below left
}elseif(f==r+1){
//below right
}elseif(f==-r){
//above
}elseif(f==(-r-1)){
//above left
}elseif(f==(-r+1){
//above right
}
```

Comment: Added diagonal directions too.